# Criação de links com imagem

Tags: html, link

Depois de colocar: `<a href="URL do site">`, em seguida devo colocar apenas o URL da imagem ou `<img src=''URL da imagem''` ?

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Portugues. Eu realmente não entendi a sua duvida e nem os seus códigos, estão sem lógica para mim, poderia editar a pergunta e tentar ser mais claro? Grato

Answer (score 2):

Há várias formas de se criar um link com imagem. A diferença depende do contexto e da semântica a ser utilizada. Veja as maneiras mais comuns:

**HTML puro**

Se a imagem faz parte do contexto da página (não é só um efeito gráfico ou um botão estilizado) convém usar a tag `img`:

```html
<a href="#"><img 
    src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/careers/careers-icon.png"
></a>
```

**Usando CSS:**

Se a imagem tem função meramente estética, é preferível o CSS.

```css
.logo {
  display:block;
  width:228px;
  height:228px;
  background:url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/careers/careers-icon.png);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="logo"></a>
```

Se puder, acrescente mais detalhes da sua necessidade [editando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/55387/edit) a pergunta, para que eu possa elaborar melhor os pontos.